# Stop querying data once reached the end

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to implememnt load more data as you scroll functioality into my web app.
I set up an onscroll listener to fetch data when user reaches the end of the page.

Here is the function to fetch data:

```
var lastKey = '';
var myData = [];

async fetchData(){
        try{
            var snap = await firebase.database().ref(category).orderByKey().startAt(lastKey).limitToFirst(15).once('value');
            snap.forEach(childSnap => {
                myData.push(childSnap.val();
                lastKey = childSnap.key;
            });
        }catch(err){
            //handle errors
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine.
How do I know that the list has ended so that I can set up a flag and stop calling the above function and notify the user that no more data is left to show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you querying each time 15 elements and the results are less than 15 elements of length you have reached the end.

Comment: But how do i know the length of elements i fetched. Do I have to do `Object.keys(snap).length`

Comment: Ok i set up an counter and increased the counter by 1 in each iteration of the forEach loop a checked if the counter was less than 15 set up a flag to stop more fetching.... Thank you. If there is a better way please reply